# How to avoid this race condition?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how I should avoid this race condition on my code:

```
.factory('cartFactory', function ($rootScope, Restangular, $q) {
    var cart = {items: false};
    var response = false;

    return {
        cart: cart,
        get: function ($cart) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            if (!cart.items) {

                cart.items = true;

                if (!response) {

                    //get items async
                    //simulated with $timeout
                    Restangular.oneUrl('cart_show', Routing.generate('en__RG__myapp.api.cart.show')).get().then(function ($response) {

                        response = $response;

                        deferred.resolve(response);
                    });
                } else {
                    //resolve promise with already loaded items
                    deferred.resolve(response);
                }

                deferred.promise.then(function ($response) {
                    angular.copy($response.cart, cart);
                    angular.copy($response.cart, $cart);
                });
            } else {
                angular.copy(cart, $cart);
            }

            return deferred.promise;
        },
        set: function ($cart) {
            angular.copy($cart, cart);
        }
    }
})
```

What I'm trying to do is that if I call cartFactory.get($cart) twice then the ajax request should be sent only once, the 2nd time I call for it then if the ajax is being loaded then it should promise to assign the content when the response is loaded completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have for my final working solution, not sure if it is ideal or not. I return the promise because I want to be able to do something after the cart is loaded

```
.factory('cartFactory', function ($rootScope, Restangular, $q) {
        var cart = {items: false};
        var promise = false;

        return {
            cart: cart,
            get: function ($cart) {

                if (!promise) {
                    //get items async
                    //simulated with $timeout
                    promise = Restangular.oneUrl('cart_show', Routing.generate('en__RG__myadpp.api.cart.show')).get().then(function ($response) {
                        angular.copy($response.cart, cart);
                        angular.copy($response.cart, $cart);
                    });
                }

                if (!cart.items) {
                    promise.then(function(){
                        angular.copy(cart, $cart);
                    })
                }

                return promise;
            },
            set: function ($cart) {
                angular.copy($cart, cart);
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

The `$http` service of angular can be configured that GET request may be cached. That means that all request to the same URL happens once no matter how often the app called them and in wich order. Also the `$resource` service can be configered the same way (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource) Parameter: `cache:true`.

If you can't use this, you may write your own cache. Please have a look at the angular sources in the function `sendReq(config, reqData, reqHeaders)` (line 7763 approximately) you may see how they do implement the cache for reuqests by using the `$cacheFactory`.

Comment: thanks Michael, nice way. I think restangular is using $http and can be configured that way as well. Just that here I may not want to cache that way, I want to decide when to cache instead (since this is a request to cart content, I may want to send a new request again at certain point). I think my question was not clear (which is my fault of course), I'm more interested in how to use promise properly here. As you can see in my code, I'm checking for response which is not the right way as response is only assigned once the request completes.

Comment: did you mean this part angular.copy($response.cart, cart); in your promis then function?

Comment: thanks Michael, you pointed me to the right direction, I'm just so confused with the promise thingy (still confused right now, obviously). I posted the updated code that is working for me.